# How to display post attachments in post edit screen in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I have created a custom post type for uploading photo albums. Users can come to the site and create albums and upload multiple photos (max. 10) from the same page - one of these images are being assigned as Feature Image.

I want all albums and photos uploaded by users against every post to be moderated by site admin. When I go to post edit page I can see title, description, category and featured image all coming up fine. How I can display other attachments (except the featured image) on edit screen?

Albums are by default being uploaded with "Pending" status, so unless I "publish", it won't be visible. But I want extend the functionality it a bit more. Like I will publish the album but want to moderate the images from the same location.

I don't want to use any ready made plugin.

Can `meta_box` help? I am still a newbie in WordPress development.

Answer (score 1):

For Create New functionality in WordPress, I suggest you that you can create custom plugin. After you can follow the steps,

- For Create the custom database or update the query on post/page table: 
  [creating database tables with plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins)
- Create Custom Post Type Or Add the post in default Post Type: [How to Add Categories to a Custom Post Type in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-categories-to-a-custom-post-type-in-wordpress/)
- Create custom meta box in custom/default post Type: [How to Create Custom WordPress Write/Meta Boxes](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes--wp-20336)

Here, sharing with you some guidelines links as per functionality.

Hope, you can get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am already done with custom post type, custom taxonomy and uploading attachments. Can you please guide me to the right direction with displaying attachments in admin edit pages? Thank you!